# 0 order Logic Construction Sequence

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am asked to exhibit a construction sequence to show whether the following is a well-formed formula;

Let S = {A, B, C, D}

$\alpha = ((A\land C) \rightarrow (((\lnot A) \land (\lnot C)) \lor B)))$

I know how to draw the tree and I think it is sufficient to show it is a wff.(is it?) But I couldn't see any examples of how to exhibit a construction sequence. Any ideas?

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean by "the tree", then just list the formulas in the tree in such an order that each compound formula comes after the subformulas from which  you formed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw a tree, starting from the "innermost" subformulas.

The terminal nodes must be obviously the *atoms* : $A,B,C$.

To $A$ add $(\lnot A)$ and to $C$ add $(\lnot C)$. Then both will produce $((\lnot A) \land (\lnot C))$ and with $B$ we have : $(((\lnot A) \land (\lnot C)) \lor B)$.

In the same way, you have to generate the other branch starting from $A$ and $C$ and producing $(A \land C)$.

Finally, use both branches to join them in the final formula, the *root* of the tree.

---

You can use instead the definition :

> A sequence $\varphi_0, \ldots, \varphi_n$ is called a *formation sequence* of $\varphi$ if
>
> > $\varphi_n = \varphi$ and for all $i ≤ n$ $\varphi_i$ is atomic, or
> >
> > $\varphi_i = (\varphi_j \square \varphi_k)$ for certain $j, k <i$, where $\square$ is a binary conncetive, or
> >
> > $\varphi_i = (¬ \varphi_j)$ for certain $j < i$.

Again, you have to start from atoms :

> $A,B,C,(\lnot A),(\lnot C), (A \land C), \ldots$